# Chrome font size changing from chrome-setting-appearance not applying to my react page

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, browser

In chrome browser when i am changing font size from appearance under setting option of chrome. It is not changing my react page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using rem unit instead of pixels in your css